# Проблемы с поиском погоды по геолокации в приложении погоды

Tags: axios, vue3, openweathermap, quasar-framework, quasar.js

Делал приложение погоды на фреймворке quasar по англоязычному гайду https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWRpEcv2nu8&t=1s

Но столкнулся с проблемой, когда поднимаю приложение на Windows, не работает поиск по моей геолокации, но обычный поиск работает.